# Downloading Image via Picasso sometimes fails

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso to download images from the web but sometimes it works and sometimes it fails. It's very irritating and I can't find a way to fix this. Any help?

My code to download image:

```
public void imageDownload(Context ctx, String url){
    Picasso.with(ctx)
            .load(spp)
            .into(getTarget(url));

}

//Using the Picasso Target Class

private Target getTarget(String url){
    final String temp = url;
    Target target = new Target(){

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + temp);
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                        ostream.flush();
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    return target;
}
```

I call this method as:

```
imageDownload(getActivity(),"image.jpg");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails". Any errors? Anything in logcat?

Comment: No Errors. It just does not save files and sometimes it does

Answer (score 0):

from documentation of method into(Target t):

> Note: This method keeps a weak reference to the {@link Target}
>   instance and will be garbage collected if you do not keep a
>   strong reference to it. To receive callbacks when an image is
>   loaded use {@link #into(android.widget.ImageView, Callback)}

You don't keep a reference to the instance of Target you have created so it can be collected by garbage collector as documentation states. This can explain random behavior you observed.

One solution is suggested in the documentation ( use into(android.widget.ImageView, Callback)).

Another solution is to keep a reference to an instance of Target.

```
target = getTarget(url); //declared as a field of a class
Picasso.with(ctx)
            .load(spp)
            .into(target);
```